# In caffe, py-faster-rcnn, "scores" return a large matrix, why?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I use the py-faster-rcnn demo to build further of my project with 20 classes.
However, I am trying to gain the softmax, last layer probability of my classes.

For example:

```
# Load the demo image
im_file = os.path.join(cfg.DATA_DIR, 'demo', image_name)

im = cv2.imread(im_file)

# Detect all object classes and regress object bounds
timer = Timer()
timer.tic()
scores, boxes = im_detect(net, im)
timer.toc()
print ('Detection took {:.3f}s for '
       '{:d} object proposals').format(timer.total_time, boxes.shape[0])

# Visualize detections for each class
CONF_THRESH = 0.8
NMS_THRESH = 0.3
for cls_ind, cls in enumerate(CLASSES[1:]):
    cls_ind += 1 # because we skipped background
    cls_boxes = boxes[:, 4*cls_ind:4*(cls_ind + 1)]
    cls_scores = scores[:, cls_ind]
    dets = np.hstack((cls_boxes,
                      cls_scores[:, np.newaxis])).astype(np.float32)
    keep = nms(dets, NMS_THRESH)
    dets = dets[keep, :]
    vis_detections(im, cls, dets, thresh=CONF_THRESH)

print scores
```

While I do the `print scores`, it gives me a very large matrix output,
instead of 1 x 20 .  I am not sure why, and how can I get the last probability matrix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw `scores` the detector outputs include overlapping detections and very low score detections as well.
Note that only after applying non-maximal suppression (aka "nms") with `NMS_THRESH=0.3` the function `vis_detection` only displays detections with confidence larger than `CONF_THRESH=0.8`.
So, if you want to look at the "true" objects, you need to check inside `vis_detection` and check only the detections it renders on the image.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, if I'd like to output an 1x20 matrix (include 0s is fine). How should I do it?

Comment: @UniversalStack for which detected box do you want to print the vector?

Comment: @UniversalStack you need to pay ck the index of the detected box you are interested in and then look at the corresponding row of `scores`

Comment: can i return just one probability matrix (1x20) for the entire picture without boxes? Thanks.

Comment: @UniversalStack WHY??? are you trying to perform image classification, or object detection?!

Comment: yes, exactly! i'd like to extract features for the entire pic.

Comment: @UniversalStack then WHY are you using faster-rcnn?! this is an architecture for **detection**. Use resnet or inception or VGG for image classification

Comment: is there a way for me to use this same structure with minimal tweak to achieve that?

Comment: @Shai - The advantage of using a detection network is that you get all objects without competition.

Comment: @UniversalStack so you are trying to do **both** detection + classification at the same `forward` pass? Depending on the backbone you are using, you can, theoretically, add a classification layer on top to get a class prob for the entire image.